# DataGridView do event after CellClick

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have DataGridView with two columns. The first column has `String` data and the second column has `Byte` data.
I want to save new data from the second column after i click a cell. When I take data from the `dataGridView1_CellClick` event, it gives me the first value, before the change.

Comment: I am confident the `DataGridView.CellClick` event is the wrong event for what you are trying to accomplish. I recommend you use the `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` event. The “Cell Click” event will fire when the user “CLICKS” into the cell, at which time the user most likely has not had time to input anything into the cell. The “Cell Value Changed” event will fire when the user tries to “leave” the cell after “changes” have been made. This event should give you the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you have a DataGridView like this :
[image]

You edit existing value in a cell and then click that cell without confirming the edit first. You want to get the value that was just entered in that cell, but not the value that was there before editing.
In that case you should read the `EditedFormattedValue` property instead of `Value`.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    // value = 42    
    byte value = byte.Parse(cell.Value as string);                        
    // editedValue = 254
    byte editedValue = byte.Parse(cell.EditedFormattedValue as string);
}
```